# Is there an implied word size for printing negative numbers in hexadecimal?

Tags: c, string-formatting

All the following produce the same output of `ffffffef`:

```
printf("%x\n", -17);
printf("%2x\n", -17);
printf("%8x\n", -17);
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%x` in `printf()` expects an `unsigned int` argument. Assuming `int` is 32-bit, in your example, `-17` is converted to `4294967279u` (`0xffffffef`). This means the formated output is at least 8 characters, even if you are using `%x` or `%2x`.

You'll get a different result if using:

```
printf("%hx\n", -17);   // ffef
```

In this example, `%hx` expects an `unsigned short`, therefore different result.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried `printf("%02x", (short)-17);` and it is still 8 hexadecimal digits.  So, whatever type the argument is, it will always be cast to an unsigned int?

Comment: @OldGeezer With format specifier `%x` or `%X`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In `%2x`, `%4x` and `%8x`, here the numbers represent the minimum character width that will be printed. Now since `ffffffef` is 8 character wide, it was printed same for all three case, because the character width is `>=` the number specified. If the number while specifying format would be `>= 8`, then you will see an extra space at the beginning (this depends on how you have specified the print format).